# ElasticSearch: Getting parent's fields from a search on the child type

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with two type (Parent/CHild relation) like this :

```
{
"myindex": {
    "mappings": {
        "b": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "a"
            },
            "properties": {                 
                "b_propertie1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                },
                "b_propertie2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                }
            }
        },
        "a": {
            "properties": {
                "a_propertie1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                },
                "a_propertie2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

And i want to make a query that returns the fields of the parent and the child

```
POST /myindex/b/_search
{
   "fields" : ["b_propertie1", "b_propertie2", "a_propertie1", "a_propertie2"],
   "query": {
      "match": {
          "b_propertie1": "SOMETHING"
      }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it ? and how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch cannot merge fields from parent and child documents.

What you can do is to use the `has_child` query, which returns you `parent` documents that have `child` documents that match your query. By specifying the `inner_hits` parameters you also get as inner objects the `child` documents that matched the query.

```
"query": {
    "has_child": {
        "type": b, 
        "query": {
            "match": {
               "b_propertie1": "SOMETHING"
            }
        },
        "inner_hits": {
            '_source': {
                'includes': ['b_propertie1', 'b_propertie2']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your app, you can merge the fields from `parent` and `child` documents to get the result you want.

I hope it helps. :)